# how to get cookie values by name from an array

Tags: php

i have a cookie that i stored an array of values inside it. now when i try to access the information by the name of the cookies it keeps giving me the error "ILLEGAL STRING OFFSET". i dont understand what this error means in my situation.

what am i doing wrong?

why cant i access the details with the name of the cookie?

here is my code:

```
    if (isset($_POST['save_details'])) {
        if (isset($_COOKIE['historyDetails'])) {



            $read_cookie=json_decode($_COOKIE['historyDetails']);


            $cookieValue=$read_cookie;
        }

        $details['totalsalary_cookie'] = $total_salary;
        if (isset($extra)) {
            foreach($extra as $e){
                $details=explode("#",$e);
                $name=$details;
                $details['extras_cookie']= $name;
            }
        }
        $details['date_cookie']= date("d/m/y");
        $details['time_cookie']= date("h:i:sa");
        $cookieValue =$details;
        setcookie("historyDetails", json_encode($cookieValue), $one_week);



    }





    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>Salary details: Total salary is BD $total_salary";
    if (count($extra_names)>0) {
        echo "<li>Extras:</li>";
        echo "<ol type = "."1".">";
        for ($i=0; $i <count($extra_names) ; $i++) {
            echo "<li>$extra_names[$i]</li>";
        } echo "</ol>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";








 die("</body></html>");
}elseif (isset($view_history)) {
  //echo $_COOKIE["historyDetails"];
    //print_r($_COOKIE);

?>
<table align="center" border="1">
<tr>
<th>Total Salary</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Extras</th>
</tr>
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE["historyDetails"])){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td align=center>".$_COOKIE["historyDetails"]["totalsalary_cookie"]."</td>";
  echo "<td align=center>".$_COOKIE["historyDetails"]["date_cookie"]."</td>";
  echo "<td align=center>".$_COOKIE["historyDetails"]["time_cookie"]."</td>";
  if(isset($_COOKIE["historyDetails"])){
    echo "<td align=center>";
    echo "<ul>";

      $emp=explode("#",$_COOKIE["historyDetails"]["extras_cookie"]);
      echo "<li>".$emp."</li>";
 
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</td>";
  }
else{
  echo "<td align=center>"."No extras Found!"."</td>";
}
  echo "</tr>";

}
die();
}
?>
```

any help?

Comment: Near the start where you `set` the cookie you effectively have `$cookieValue=json_decode( $_COOKIE['historyDetails'] );` but then overwrite that variable later so is there any need to read the cookie at that point?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius so what am i supposed to do? delete that line of code? because i did and still same problem

Comment: That line is not causing the issue - just wondered if there was a purpose I did not see with the above. I'm trying to create a test for this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the content you are trying to set in the cookie I had to improvise to test this code. In my tests the contents of the cookie were urlencoded which is why - in conjunction with the fact that the value is json encoded, I suspect, you were not able to directly access the values held within the cookie by name.

```
<?php 

    $_POST['save_details']=true;
    
    $cname='historyDetails';

    $one_week=strtotime( 'now + 1 week' );
    $total_salary=mt_rand(150000,250000);
    $extra=array(
        'banana'    =>  'yellow#curvy#healty',
        'snow'      =>  'cold#white#fun'
    );
    
    

    if ( isset( $_POST['save_details'] ) ) {
    
        if( isset( $_COOKIE[ $cname ] ) ) {
            $cookieValue=json_decode( $_COOKIE[ $cname ] );
        }

        $details['totalsalary_cookie'] = $total_salary;
        
        if( isset( $extra ) ) {
            foreach( $extra as $e ){
                $details=explode("#",$e);
                $name=$details;
                $details['extras_cookie']= $name;
            }
        }
        $details['date_cookie']= date("d/m/y");
        $details['time_cookie']= date("h:i:sa");
        $cookieValue=$details;
        
        
        setcookie( $cname, json_encode( $cookieValue, JSON_HEX_APOS ), $one_week );
    }
    
        
    if( isset( $_COOKIE['historyDetails'] ) ){
        $json=json_decode( urldecode( $_COOKIE[ $cname ] ) );
        printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($json,true));
    }
    
?>
```

This yields a cookie string like this:

```
%7B%220%22%3A%22cold%22%2C%221%22%3A%22white%22%2C%222%22%3A%22fun%22%2C%22extras_cookie%22%3A%5B%22cold%22%2C%22white%22%2C%22fun%22%5D%2C%22date_cookie%22%3A%2220%5C%2F03%5C%2F21%22%2C%22time_cookie%22%3A%2201%3A10%3A27pm%22%7D
```

But when decoded using the code shown yields:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => cold
    [1] => white
    [2] => fun
    [extras_cookie] => Array
        (
            [0] => cold
            [1] => white
            [2] => fun
        )

    [date_cookie] => 20/03/21
    [time_cookie] => 01:09:25pm
)
```

From that you should find it is easy enough to access items from the cookie:

```
echo $json->extras_cookie[0], $json->date_cookie; //etc
```